# What's the difference between `overflow-block` and `overflow` (and `block-overflow`)?

Tags: css, overflow

From the docs:
**Overflow**:

> The overflow shorthand CSS property sets what to do when an element's content is too big to fit in its block formatting context.

**overflow-block**

> The overflow-block CSS property sets what shows when content overflows a block-level element's block start and block end edges.

Does that mean `overflow-block` is only for block elements?

At first, I thought `overflow-block` will be something like [block-overflow](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/block-overflow/) but that's not the case here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-block: _“The overflow-block property maps to overflow-y or overflow-x depending on the writing mode of the document.”_ - I think this might be the most important part here. You can specify the overflow behavior on the element’s “main axis”, but have that automatically consider either the Y or the X axis as “main”, depending on the writing mode.

Answer (score -2):

No, overflow-block is literally used to block the overflow property from the element. You can play around with the example link given in the comment section